# On inputting a string of more than 10 characters in a char array of size 10 and outputting it, it shows the whole array instead of the first 10. Why?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char d[10];
cout<<"Enter any string which has more than 10 characters in it";
cin>>d;
cout<<"The string you entered is "<<endl;
cout<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose you entered "1234567890123", then it should show only "123456789" instead of the whole thing you entered, but it is doing the latter.

Comment: Going out of bounds of an array leads to *undefined behavior*. Just don't do it.

Comment: Pure luck! this is a buffer overrun, and the result is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can be anything, which is sometimes the correct result. But it probably just ran past the end of the buffer on the stack and overwrote some memory that could cause all kinds of problems. Use `std::string` instead of a fixed-size C array, or use a "safe" function from `stdio.h` that lets you specify the size of the buffer.

Comment: @parktomatomi What does `std::string` do? And where should I add it?

Comment: It's the idiomatic way to store a string in C++. You can use it in most places instead of `char *`. It allocates memory dynamically for the characters, and automatically grows as you need. Also frees memory automatically so you don't need to worry about doing that yourself. Change `char d[10];` to `std::string d;` and you're gold.

Comment: Programmer first broke the rules.  Code is returning the in kind - it then behaves anyway it wants.

Comment: Your question is about your expectations not being met. So you need to give your expectations--but you don't. Otherwise, all we can say is, the program does what the language definition says it may do, and we can't critique your misconceptions. Don't expect us to tell you what each step does. You should tell us what you think each step does. That includes confirming  what operators do by reading the manual and/or an introduction that tells you exactly. PS It seems likely that you think `cin>>d` does something that is not what it does.

Comment: @philipxy `cin>>d` is used to accept an input(which in this case is a character array) from the keyboard, am I wrong?

Comment: @philipxy Also, I have already written about what I was expecting from the program after the code in its description.

Comment: Your description of >> is too vague. Also please go read what it does in an authoritative reference--that is part of research before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to undefined behavior land.  Currently `cin` uses a function in the form of

```
template< class CharT, class Traits>
basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& operator>>( basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& st, CharT* s );
```

in order to read in the input into the array.  Since it uses a pointer, it doesn't know how big your array is and will happily overflow your buffer causing undefined behavior.

One of the symptoms of this, which you have observed, is it writes the data into memory that your not allowed to access, but that access doesn't cause an error.  When you go to read the content of the array, you get the full input even through you shouldn't.  You can't rely on this behavior though.  The program could just crash or anything else can happen.  Undefined behavior means any result can happen.

Starting in C++ 20 this wont happen anymore when using an array.  The signature of the function is changing to

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, std::size_t N >
basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& operator>>( basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& st, CharT (&s)[N] );
```

and since it is taking the array by reference, it knows its size and can stop itself from overflowing the buffer.

---

It should be noted this is a breaking change.  Code like

```
auto p = new char[100];
std::cin >> std::setw(20) >> p;
```

which is legal C++17 code will not compile in C++20 since `p` is not an array.  You can see the paper about this change here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0487r1.html

---

If you switch to use a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) then you don't need to worry about this at all as the `std::string` will grow to fit the input entered.  That would give you

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Enter any string which has more than 10 characters in it";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << "The string you entered is \n" << input;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Understood the use of `std::string` but everything you wrote above it flew over my head, can you please explain in layman's language?

Comment: @DravitGupta Basically the language let you shot yourself in the foot.  Since the function takes a pointer it no longer know how big the array is so it will store as many characters as it wants to.  If it overflows the buffer then you have undefined behavior and any result is correct.  The fact that it showed the full input was "luck".  It could have just as easily crashed the program.

Comment: You said " Since the function takes a pointer it no longer know how big the array is", what does that mean? Understood the rest.

Comment: "One of the symptoms of this is it writes the data into memory that your not allowed to access" is one possibility, but not the required behavior.

Comment: @DravitGupta C++ has a "feature" called array to pointer decay.  What that means is that an array can be implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element in the array.  When this happens you are left with a pointer to the start of the array.  Because it's just a pointer, there is no way for the function to figure out the size of the array it points to.  A pointer could point to a single object, or an array of a billion objects.  It's all the same as far as the pointer is concerned.  Make sense?

Comment: Sorry to ask again but "there is no way for the **function** to figure out the size of the array it points", which function are you talking about?

Comment: @DravitGupta The `operator <<` function.  All operators for classes in C++ are functions.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, arrays and pointers are interchangeable.

```
char* a;
char b[123];

// these two call the same function.
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
```

The stream operator `>>` has no idea how much storage you have allocated wherever that char* points to, it just starts writing until its done.

Now imagine what happens when you get a case like this

```
char foo[2];
bool bar = false;

cin>>foo;
if (bar)
{
  ...
}
```

`foo` and `bar` are next to each other on the stack.  As `cin>>` writes past the end of `foo`, it will stomp all over the memory reserved for `bar`.

If you've ever heard of a "stack buffer overflow" attack, this is the sort of thing they're talking about, and incidentally where (I presume) stackoverflow.com gets its name.  Overwriting a buffer on the stack sufficiently to write Bad Things into the stack, like changing where the function will return to (to a different part of the same overflow), and a bunch of instructions you probably don't want your computer to execute.